# How does GHASH used in GCM behave as a universal hashing function?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, gcm, universal-hash

As per my understanding, a Universal Hash Function isn't a cryptographic hash function & it's output isn't uniformly distributed. However, this is still secure because it's actually a family of functions & one or more of the random inputs to the function decides which function is actually picked from the family of functions & this is what makes it secure.

However, these are the Parameters to GHASH

$GHASH(H, A, C)$ where

$H = E(K, 0^w)$

$K$ is the encryption key & it's fixed, so a new one isn't picked every time, which means $H$ is also fixed.

$A$ is the Additional Authenticated Data

$C$ is the Ciphertext

So how exactly is this a universal hashing function - what is the family & how exactly are we randomly choosing from the family?

Comment: Note that a universal hash function is not immediately a secure MAC (generally). For GHASH you choose the concrete function from the family using your choice of $H$. More details in an answer later (probably).

Comment: @SEJPM - yeah, that's my point - in this case H is not chosen randomly. It's fixed.

Comment: Ah, I see, it is actually chosen uniformly, because an adversary doesn't know $K$ and thus doesn't know $H$ (and the block cipher is a PRF). The thing you are probably confused about is the fact that $H$ is not chosen freshly for _each message_. But for the universal hash function property you don't need to pick the function freshly for each message.

Comment: @SEJPM - that's exactly what confuses me. I thought a universal hash used something like a nonce to pick a diff function from a family of function. If it uses a fixed key, then how is it different from regular hash functions used in Keyed Hashing? As a matter of fact, Boneh in his lecture on CarterWegman MAC calls the MAC as a One Time MAC. I am confused now as to how the CWMAC is a Onetime MAC

Comment: I believe the point is that for every new instantiation of GCM we want that GHASH is a good UHF. Which should be the case since assuming that AES is a good PRF then $E_k(0) = k_{\text{GHASH}}$ is a random key. And the security requirement for a UHF is that for a random key $k$ $P_[H_k(m1) = H_k(m2)] \leq \epsilon$

Comment: Usually you build a one-time mac out of a UHF by requiring a second key (which must always be fresh) and use that one to mask the UHF output. A carter-wegman MAC then reduces that to a computational assumption by using a PRF and a fixed secret key on a public random value to generate the mask.

Comment: @SEJPM - yes, I assumed that a One-time-MAC is not secure unless you use a fresh second key every time. And I assumed that any MAC built with a universal hashing function is a one-time MAC.

Comment: Universal hash functions are confusing, especially for the layman, and I have been unable to find a description on the Internet that explains them clearly with examples.

Comment: @Patriot - yes, you don't find a good desc/examples of a UHF in a crypto book. You may find one in an algorithms book - but there it's more tailored to be used in a hash-table implementation - so the considerations are different.

Comment: @user93353  Exactly.  I wish someone would fix it.

Comment: The book by Boneh and Shoup deals quite extensively on the topic, or at least for aspect relevant to cryptography https://toc.cryptobook.us/

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $H=E_k(0)$ is used to choose from the family. This is not a problem, and here is some intuition on why.

The output of the hash function is not leaked in clear, it is "hidden" by xoring with $E_k(iv,ctr=0)$ which is different per each encrypted message (in contrast to $H=E_k(0)$). Otherwise it would be indeed trivial to recover H as the UHF is linear.

Intuitively, the property used is that UHF should be hard to blindly predict the difference for any two inputs without knowing the key, even with multiple attempts, but without revealing the UHF value on each attempt.

Note that the "difference" matters here because in forgery attempts you are allowed to reuse the nonce, so guessing the right difference would suffice for a break. For example, given $$(iv,m,t),~~ t=E_k(iv,ctr=0)\oplus GHASH(m))$$ and guessing the difference $\Delta = GHASH(m)\oplus GHASH(m')$ would allow to forge
$$
(iv,m',t'),~~ t'=t\oplus \Delta=E_k(iv,ctr=0)\oplus GHASH(m').
$$